# Not able to open my downloads through terminal in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal

Why can’t I view files in my `Downloads/` folder using a simple `ls`?

```
DEVs-MacBook-Pro-3:~ dev$ ls
Desktop         Music           Python
Documents       OneDrive        Samsung
Downloads       Pictures        data.ipynb
Library         Pipfile         notebook cv.ipynb
Movies          Public          opt
DEVs-MacBook-Pro-3:~ dev$ cd Downloads/
DEVs-MacBook-Pro-3:Downloads dev$ ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
DEVs-MacBook-Pro-3:Downloads dev$
```

Comment: How is this related to Python, or to SO in general?

Comment: Try `ls -l` to see the permissions of the `Downloads` folder. It's likely that your user does not have permissions to that folder, for whatever reasons. You can fix this with a `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/Downloads`

Answer (score 6):

It is a "Security" Feature of MacOSX.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395631/allow-all-applications-to-access-desktop-documents-and-downloads-in-catalina

Try going to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access -> Unlock the panel and click + and add the Terminal App. This is fairly dangerous and has security implications

Comment: Can you explain why this is dangerous?

Comment: See this answer for details: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438689/is-allowing-full-disk-access-to-safari-dangerous